# How to pass data from a modal with Expo Router using React-Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, expo-router

Newbie to expo-router & React-Native

I have two screens (a & b) for example, b being a modal which is presented over a.

How would I go about passing data from screen b (the modal) back to screen a?

### File Structure

```
app
-(tabs)
--account
---index.jsx (screen a)
-create-account
--index.jsx (screen b)
```

Usually when you are adding a screen to the stack you would use `useLocalSearchParams();` however, I am popping a screen off the stack and the screen behind is already rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of calling `router.back()` you can call `router.push({})` with an empty pathname

### Screen Receiving Data

```
const params = useLocalSearchParams();
const { ANY_PARAMS_HERE } = params;
```

### Screen Sending Data

```
const goBack = () => {
  router.push({
    pathname: "/",
    params: {
      SOME_OBJECT: SOME_OBJECT_VALUE,
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my specific scenario, I needed to choose specific values from a separate view, presented as a modal, while utilizing `Expo Router` and `React Hook Form`. If you've come across a more efficient solution, I'd greatly appreciate your insights. I require the pre-filled values to remain intact while only adding the newly entered values (in a seperate modal/page) to my form. This solution should also be compatible with other form libraries, such as `Formik`.

**planner/_layout.tsx**

```
export default function PlannerLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack initialRouteName="create">
      <Stack.Screen name="create" />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="selectCategory"
        // This will display the page as a standalone modal page, as commonly seen in many apps
        options={{ presentation: 'modal', animation: 'fade_from_bottom' }}
      />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

**planner/selectCategory.tsx**

```
export default function SelectCategory() {
  const router = useRouter()

  function back() {
    // Return back to the view containing the form
    router.push({
      pathname: '/planner/create',
      params: {
        description: 'A description from another view', // <-- Add your value(s) here
      },
    })
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={back}>back</Button>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**planner/create.tsx**

```
export default function Create() {
  const router = useRouter()
  // We will get all the values from here
  const params = useLocalSearchParams<{ description?: string }>()

  const methods = useForm({...})

  function openSelectCategoryModal() {
    router.push('/planner/selectCategory')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add the new value to your existing form values
    if (params.description != null) methods.setValue('description', params.description)
  }, [params])

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
    <Button onPress={openSelectCategoryModal}>open seperate modal view</Button>
      ...
    </FormProvider>
  )
```